# Calculating the exhaust velocity using conservation of momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science

I was just wondering if i did this correctly

$$p_{exhaust}=-p_{rocket}$$
$$m_{e}v_{e}=-m_{r}v_{r}$$
$$v_{e}=\frac{-m_{r}v_{r}}{m_{e}}$$
I used data from a Saturn V simulation by Robert A. Braeunig to find out mass flow rate, $m_{e}$ and then used the instaneous mass of the rocket, $m_{r}$ and the respective velocity

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are *trying* to do here, but the final equation looks wrong, because it ways that for a rocket sitting on the launch pad with $v_r = 0$, the exhaust velocity is also $0$ so the rocket is never going to take off!

Comment: The *change* in momenta at any instant must balance, not the *absolute* momenta.    You need the *rocket equation*.   [Try this description.](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/2017/20170428-the-rocket-equation-part-1.html)